# Opening a photo in pop up modal

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Sorry, I have found lots of answers here regarding modals and jQuery, but I cant find anything that helps me. I have a form that has photos. People should be able to click on the photo and it would open a larger version in a modal window. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to pass the value of the photo name to the modal. Here is what I have:
php/HTML:

```
 <?php
    $imgno = 1;
    $dir = "memberphotos/$id/";
    $qry = "SELECT PhotoName, Visible, Likes FROM photolist WHERE UserID = " . $id;
    if ($result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'], $qry)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="album-image">
                    <a href="#" class="thumb" data-action="edit" src='<?php $dir.$row['PhotoName']; ?>'>
                        <img src="<?php echo $dir . $row['PhotoName'] . "_thumb.jpg"; ?>"
                             class="img-responsive"/>
                    </a>

                    <a href="#" class="name">
                        <i class="fa-heart-o"> <?php if (!empty($row['Likes'])) {echo $row['Likes']." Likes";} ?> </i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="image-options">
                        <a href="#" data-action="edit" data-id="<?php echo $row['PhotoName'];?>"><i class="fa-heart-o"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php
            $imgno = $imgno+1;}
    } 
?>
```

Now for the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Sample Javascript code for this page
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        // Edit Modal
        $('.gallery-env a[data-action="edit"]').on('click', function (ev) {
            var id = ('data-id');
            ev.preventDefault();
            $("#gallery-image-modal").modal('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, the code... I hard coded an image name into the img src to make sure it works, which it does. I'm just trying to get the photo name from the database, stored for each photo and passed to the modal.

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="gallery-image-modal" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-gallery-image">
                <img src="<?php echo $dir . '2017-02-28_1_B828A.jpg'; ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            <i class="fa-heart"> <?php echo $row['Likes']; ?> Likes</i>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
<?php if ($id == $_SESSION['uid']) {?>
            <div class="modal-footer modal-gallery-top-controls">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Set as Main</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-red">Delete image</button>
            </div>
<?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure this out... a little help for a humble learning coder?

Comment: Is your question "How do I pass a value to an Ajax URL, based on an element in the page?" If so, you can get rid of all this PHP and make your question much more likely to get answered. See [mcve]

Comment: in the `ev` Object you also have the element, that triggered that event -> you can get the `src` from there. Then set the `src` of the image-element (give that an id) in the modal to that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .on() events isn't always the best solution. You also don't need to wrap the image inside of an a tag.

```
<img src="<?php echo $dir . $row['PhotoName'] . "_thumb.jpg"; ?> onclick="openImgModal('<?php echo $dir . $row['PhotoName']; ?>')" class="img-responsive"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function openImgModal(img_src)
{
    $('.modal-gallery-image').html('<img src="'+img_src+'" class="img-responsive" />');
    $("#gallery-image-modal").modal('show');
}
```

maybe add some CSS to indicate the image is clickable

```
.img-responsive
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: You are a God. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way that does not include inline javascript

HTML

```
<div class="cover">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="modalPhoto">
    <img src="" />
</div>
```

CSS (can adjust this for your needs)

```
.cover {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    z-index:9997;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
}   

body.open .cover {
    display:block;
}

.modalPhoto {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9998;
    width:680px;
    height:550px;
    background:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0 0 15px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-1500px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-350px;
    -webkit-transition:800ms margin-top ease-in-out;
    transition:800ms margin-top ease-in-out;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:10px solid #fff;
}   

body.open .modalPhoto {
    margin-top:-285px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.gallery-env a img').on('click', function(e) {
  var photo = $(this).data('src');
  $('.modalPhoto').find('img').attr('src', photo);
  $('body').addClass('open');
});
$('.cover').on('click',function() {
  $('body').removeClass('open');
});
```

Let me know if any of this doesn't make sense